# How do you secure individual databases in RethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb

I know we can secure the driver port using an authentication key, but how can we secure individual databases?

http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/security/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no way to do this; if someone has access to your cluster, they have access to all the databases in it.

Comment: There must be a reason for this?

Comment: We'll eventually add that feature, but we want to focus on some other things first. See https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/218

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the link. This would be a critical requirement for our studios